# How to run animation with blocked UI thread in Qt Widgets app?

Tags: qt, qtwidgets

In QML you can use `Animator` type to "animate on the scene graph's rendering thread even when the UI thread is blocked."

How can I achieve the same thing for Qt Widgets?

Basically, I want something like:

```
1) start loading screen / splash-screen
2) start GUI-blocking operation
3) stop loading screen / splash-screen
```

It is not possible to move the ui-blocking operation to a separate thread (Widgets are being created). I cannot modify this part.

I tried `QQuickWidget` and `QQuickView` containing the splash-screen scene with an `Animator` inside but it didn't work - they got blocked as well.

EDIT: In the separate thread I read the file containing the UI description. Then I recursively create hundreds of Widgets (including QQuickWidgets, QLabels for images, Web views etc.).

Point of the question was to see if there is a "workaround" for that (e.g. displaying the aforementioned QML scene in some separate window with an own event loop). Unfortunately at this point not much more can be done about the overall design of the above.

Comment: You should not block the GUI thread. If you say that the blocking task is creating widgets, that smells like a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the widgets you're creating do too much work. You have to specify exactly how many widgets you're creating, and how. Show some example code. In general, the GUI thread is for cooperative multitasking - if you have something that "blocks", break it down into tiny chunks. For example, suppose that you're processing some XML or json file to build the UI. You could have that task do it one widget at a time, and be invoked each time the event loop is about to block (i.e. use a zero-duration "timer" and invert control).

You should also do the maximum possible amount of work outside of the gui thread. I.e. the UI description should be read and converted to an efficient representation that encapsulates the work to be done in the main thread. This conversion has to be done asynchronously.

The simplest way to accomplish that is to encapsulate each widget's creation in a lambda that refers to some context object. Such a lambda would have the signature `[...](BatchContext &ctx)`. The vector of those lambdas would be kept by the `CreationContext` object as well:

```
class BatchContext : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  using Op = std::function<void(CreationContext &)>;
  using QObject::QObject;
  // useful for Op to keep track of where things go
  void push(QWidget *w) { m_stack.push_back(w); }
  QWidget *pop() { return m_stack.isEmpty() ? nullptr : m_stack.takeLast(); }
  QWidget *top() const { return m_stack.isEmpty() ? nullptr : m_stack.last(); }
  int stackSize() const { return m_stack.size(); }
  bool stackEmpty() const { return m_stack.isEmpty(); }

  Q_SLOT void startExec() {
    if (m_execIndex < ops.size())
      m_execTimer.start(0, this);
  }
  template <typename F>
  void addOp(F &&op) { m_ops.push_back(std::forward<F>(op)); }
  ...
private:
  QVector<Op> m_ops;
  QVector<QWidget *> m_stack;
  QBasicTimer m_execTimer;
  int m_execIndex = 0;
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *ev) override {
    if (ev->timerId() == m_execTimer.timerId())
      if (!exec())
        m_execTimer.stop();
  }
  /// Does a unit of work, returns true if more work is available
  bool exec() {
    if (m_execIndex < m_ops.size())
      m_ops.at(m_execIndex++)(*this);
    return m_execIndex < ops.size();
  }
};
```

After the context is created asynchronously, it can be passed to the main thread where you can then invoke `startExec()` and the widgets will be created one-at-a-time. The stack is but an example of how you might implement one aspect of widget creation process - the tracking of what widget is the "current parent".

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question to answer your remarks. Long story short: it is indeed building the UI from the file-based representation, although not much can be done about it now. Therefore the need for more "ugly" solution.